# Deletion of row in MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I have been developing a CRUD application using PHP & MySQL database.

I was succeeded by creating, displaying, updation parts. But I stuck at the deletion part of a row from a database table.

I tried my best solving all the PHP shown errors but now in final it is now showing a message which I wrote to echo in case of failure.

I request someone to please help me with this problem.

Thankyou in advance.

**Code I wrote for deletion:**

```
    //include database connection

    include 'db_connect.php';


    //$mysqli->real_escape_string() function helps us prevent attacks such as SQL injection

    $query = "DELETE 

    FROM `grocery`

    WHERE `GrocerID` ='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'

    limit 0,1";
    //execute query

    if( $mysqli->query($query) ){

    //if successful deletion

    echo "User was deleted.";

    }else{

    //if there's a database problem

    echo "Database Error: Unable to delete record.";

    }
    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

**Code I wrote for delete link in display table:**

```
//just preparing the delete link to delete the record

echo "<a href='delete.php?id={$GrocerID}'>Delete</a>";
```

**Code I wrote for db config:**

```
<?php

//set connection variables

$host = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "secret";

$db_name = "crud"; //database name

//connect to mysql server

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

//check if any connection error was encountered

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: no `real_escape_string` will not prevent SQL injections. use prepared statements instead when handling user input take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: echo the query and see whether it prints what you have expected

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and got working, can you update the code and see if this works?

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "secret";
$db_name = "crud"; //database name

//connect to mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

//check if any connection error was encountered
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
exit;
}

//  Delete row
if ($mysqli->query (sprintf( "DELETE FROM grocery WHERE email = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' LIMIT 1") )) {
    printf ( "Affected Rows  %d rows.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows ); 
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a connection :

```
if( $mysqli->query($con, $query) ){
```

Comment: I did that in db config na??

Sorry if I'm wrong, I'm a newbie can you please be more elaborative.